# Turning a callback which gets called multiple times into a generator function

Tags: javascript, callback, generator

I have a function that fetches rows of a database asynchronously, and calls a callback function for each row.  I am trying to write a wrapper which is a generator function which yields each time a row is returned, but I am not seeing how to properly yield.

The original code looks something like this:

```
db.each(query, (err, row) => {
  // do something here with row
}, () => {
  // called after the last row is returned
})
```

I'm familiar with how a generator works, but the yield seems to belong in the generator function itself, not in an anonymous function.  So I think something like this wouldn't work:

```
function* dbEach(db, query) {
    db.each(query, (err, row) => {
      yield row
    })
}
```

When I actually *try* this I get an error "Unexpected identifier".

I looked a bit further and it appears that ES2018 now has asynchronous iterators which are supposed to make this possible.  However, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how exactly I can use async iterators in the case where I already have a callback which is getting called multiple times.

Comment: You're `yield`ing from an inner, non-generator, function.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need here, `function* dbEach(db, query) {
    yield db.each(query, (err, row) => row);
}`

Comment: @Rikin oh... maybe `yield*`?

Comment: How can you tell when all `.each` callbacks have finished? Is there a `.finished` property, or something like that you can check? (Maybe there's a better function than `each` from which you can get all rows as an *array*, that would make things far easier)

Comment: @CertainPerformance There is another optional callback for that.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: `yield*` can only be used on a generator function. Your `db.each` seems like regular function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated

Comment: Not sure whether this is a duplicate of [How to convert Node.js async streaming callback into an async generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50862698/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the generator `async`, then `await` a Promise that resolves with all rows (so that you have reference to a `rows` variable on the top level of `dbEach`), and then you can yield each row in that `rows` array:

```
async function* dbEach(db, query) {
  const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rows = [];
    db.each(query, (err, row) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else rows.push(row);
    }, () => resolve(rows));
  });
  for (const row of rows) {
    yield row;
  }
}
```

Use with:

```
for await (const row of dbEach(...)) {
  // do something
}
```

It looks like `.each` is designed for running a callback on each row, which isn't exactly optimal for what you're trying to accomplish here with a generator - if possible, it would be great if there was a method in your database that allows you to get an *array* of rows instead, for example:

```
async function* dbEach(db, query) {
  const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.getAllRows(query, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(rows);
    });
  });
  for (const row of rows) {
    yield row;
  }
}
```

Though, I don't think that a generator helps a lot here - you may as well just `await` a Promise that resolves to the rows, and iterate over the rows synchronously:

```
function getRows(db, query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.getAllRows(query, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(rows);
    });
  });
}

const rows = await getRows(...);
for (const row of rows) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with getting an array of rows is that there could be (for instance) 50 million rows buffered up in memory...

Comment: Given that the callback is called by the db's *internals*, and that said call isn't controllable / throttleable from the outside, I'm somewhat doubtful that a generator would be able to interface with that *without* having many rows possibly "pile up". Eg, what if the callback is called 1000 times before the generator consumer has had the spare resources to do its operation?

Comment: How does `await` work without being inside the body of  `async`?

Comment: @zer00ne OP is looking to use the new asynchronous iteration syntax, which of course requires its `await` to be inside an `async` function, but the problem OP was running into was figuring out how to set up the generator, not with how to use `await`. The containing block would have to be an `async` function, of course